# Inspect SpriteKit Scene at Runtime

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, ios-simulator

I am generating my levels in SpriteKit via code (in Swift), and its not working out entirely how I'd like. Is there a way to inspect the scene of the simulator at run time. E.g. So I can view how things are being placed outside the visible screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Believe me, level editor via code rarely is a good idea. There are exceptions but if you need static levels then you should find another way to defined it.

### How can you see your entire scene?

AFAIK you con't with Xcode 7, however you can change how the scene is resize in order to show the full scene inside the view. Depending by the size of your level you can judge whether this is solutions fits your case.

Just open GameViewController.swift and change this

```
scene.scaleMode = AspectFill
```

into this

```
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFit
```

Now your scene will be compressed to fit the size of the screen. Of course don't forget to restore the original value once you are done.

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured out the issue in my code, but I think it would still be a useful feature for Apple to have. I am defining a base level in a file, loading it and displaying, thereby allowing the user to have a level editor in game later.